# Python/Pandas filter groupby aggregate sum and return all matching row data

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas/python. I am trying to filter all data from csv if the aggregate sum of `groupby ('year','month,'Unit','Name')` is <1000. I would ideally like to return all data that meets that criteria.

My data looks like

```
[Unit Operation Date Item_Description Category Name year quarter month][1]
```

so far I have been Ising the pd.pivot_table function

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['year', 'quarter','month','Unit'], values = ['Name'],aggfunc=pd.Series.nunqiue)
```

Essentially I am trying to filter out aggregate sum(grouped by year, month, and name) that are greater than 1000 but would like to see the more detailed data. I'm new to pandas/python so thought I could filter through python and then be able to drill down in excel. Also, most people at my work use excel.

[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQpCe.jpg)

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output ?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. just added a photo.

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas Groupby` provides you with a `filter` mechanism which takes in a subset of dataframe/group and the `filterfunction`

A particular subset of data will be selected if the `filterfunction` is **True** and will be dropped if not.

In your case, you want to select the row's where for every (group) `('year', 'month, 'Name')` where `sum('Invoice Amount')` **< 1000**

So, our `filterfunciton` and corresponding code, can be set to

```py
less_than_1000 = lambda subset: subset['Invoice Amount'].sum() < 1000

filter_df = df.groupby(
             ['year', 'month', 'Name']).filter(lambda grp: less_than_1000(grp))

filter_df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'Name'])['Invoice Amount'].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.